# Bad status register?

Tags: c++, keyboard, x86, kernel, hardware

Working on a project. Professor gave us a .zip file with some tests, so we can see if our project is working correctly. We are building a small kernel in c++.

Anyhow, there is a thread that waits for a keyboard interrupt (event9.wait()) and after that it should put characters in a buffer or end the program (if you press "esc").

```
while (!theEnd) {

        event9.wait();

        status = inportb(0x64); // reading status reg. from 64h
        while (status & 0x01){ //while status indicates that keys are pressed
                ....
```

I checked and I am certain that it waits for the interrupt regularly. The problem occurs because status&0x01 is 0.

Then I got the part of code that gets the characters from 0x60 and it worked just fine.

Is there something wrong with the code of test files? And if yes, what? If the code is correct what could cause the problem?

I could change the test files, but I need a good reason to do so. And so far the only reason I have is that it doesn't work.

*note: comments are translated from Serbian, but I am almost certain they are translated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `status & 0x01` is perfectly fine. However, you would need to read the port again after reading port 0x60 - it may well be that you do that later on in the code, but I personally would just re-write the code to:

```
    while ((status = inportb(0x64)) & 0x01){ //while status indicates that keys are pressed
            ....
```

Note that you shouldn't read port 0x64 again inside the loop in this case.

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere? Because it doesn't get in the while loop.
What can be the problem? I can't see the scenario where my code influences this part. So far I only changed a interrupt function for entry no. 9 in the IVT. I am really stuck at this :(

Comment: Sorry, debugging this sort of problem "remotely" is very hard. Do you actually get an interrupt from the keyboard? If you write some code to read port 64 directly in the interrupt handler, what happens?

Comment: I solved the problem.
It occurs. The thing is that there is an indicator should the old routine (=handler?) be called in the new routine. I turned it off and now it works.

Comment: I guess the old routine (=handler?) was "stealing" the indicator? Because in the new routine the sequence was: signal the thread, execute old routine, code after "event9.wait()". Anyway, thanks a lot [: You saved me hours ^^